# How to always run module method before any other method in module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a module i am working and i want to somehow call another method first which makes a check and then run the actual method that was called.

my module structure is like this

```
module Python
   module Api
     def call_this_method_everytime
       if A
         go ahead and call the actual method being called
       else
         stop here do not call he method it was supposed to call
       end
     end

     def when_i_call_this_method

     end

     def or_this_method

     end
   end
end
```

I found some complex solutions but did not work in my case as most wanted to call a class before intercepting the method.

any clues?

Comment: give an example? What is that method that you want to call? You want to call it from where, before what and do what?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev as i said, i want a method inside the module to be called, before any other method in the module. Like a before_action hook in the controller

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i updated my post, does it have more clarity now?

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou you can just copy the method you want to run on every method, It is more explicit and avoids magic

Comment: @SamD yeah but when it needs to be done eight times or more ( according to the number of methods i have in there), where is the DRY principle in that?

Comment: yes, much better. This can be done with a bit of metaprogramming black magic (`alias_method` + `define_method`). In a nutshell, you need to redefine your methods, so that `when_i_call_this_method` will now call `call_this_method_everytime` and, if check is successful, delegate to `when_i_call_this_method_old`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev interesting - thank you i will look into that!